# Java want to improve a code snip

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, char

I wish to improve this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
        if (arrayA[i] == arrayB[j]) {
            arrayA[i] = ' ';
            arrayB[j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

The costly operation is

```
arrayA[i] = ' ';
arrayB[j] = ' ';
```

If I comment that out the code runs from 180ms to 12ms...

Need something similar so I can count the empty array.

Comment: If you comment out those two lines, the compiler is probably noticing that your loops don't do anything and is optimizing them away completely. I doubt that the timing results reflect the cost of those two lines. What do `arrayA` and `arrayB` contain initially?

Comment: Comment out one line and what is its performance? That will allow you to theoretically determine the cost of just one set operation. Two set operations would be the difference multiplied by 2.

Comment: @Compass - Unless commenting out one line affected how often the body of the `if` statement was entered.

Comment: @TedHopp ah you got me there. Running it through my head though, it doesn't appear to do that. It appears to be single-pass until A[i] is found and then it doesn't need to find anymore.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Do you get correct results with it?

Comment: If you comment out those 2 lines, the code simply wastes CPU cycles. You could improve performance if the strings are very large but otherwise you may want to simply add a test to not perform the second loop if `arrayA[i]==' '`

Comment: @TedHopp The java compiler doesn't optimize *anything*. Empty loops and other blocks stick around, to be removed at runtime.

Comment: @tbodt - That's probably correct. The JIT compiler might well remove the loops after the first pass, though.

Comment: @Pshemo The purpose is to see if String a contains in String b. Yes, the code works, but it needs to be more efficient.

Comment: The code you posted really doesn't look like "String a contains in String b". Edit your question and state clearly what's the goal. Also add more code. Modifying a string to find out something sounds plain wrong. Optimizing line by line is pure nonsense, that's surely not how computers/compilers work.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve this by breaking out of the inner loop as soon as the `if` condition is met. You can also improve performance using a temporary variable inside the outer loop to avoid constantly doing subscripting of `arrayA` inside the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    char ch = arrayA[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
        if (ch == arrayB[j]) {
            ch = ' ' = arrayB[j] = ' ';
            break;
        }
    }
    arrayA[i] = ch;
}
```

The reason it is safe to break out of the inner loop is that once `ch` (or `arrayA[i]` in the original code) is set to `' '`, then on subsequent passes of the inner loop, the `if` test will only succeed when `arrayB[j]` is already `' '`, so the assignments would be leaving the values unchanged (and simply consuming cpu cycles).

Comment: Do you still get the same output as before or you are only changing the first occurrence of same element then break out of the inner loop.

Comment: @Juniar - **IF** the original `arrayB` values do not include any `' '` characters, then this will get the same output. (At least I think so--this has not been tested.) If they do, then the `break;` statement needs to be removed to get the same output. Even without the `break;`, the use of a local variable in the outer loop should still speed things up some.

Comment: @Juniar - On further reflection, one should always break out of the inner loop as soon as the `if` test succeeds. I explain why in the edit to my answer.

Comment: Assuming we have an array of characters such that; arrayA ={'A', 'K', 'N', 'Y'}; with arrayB ={'A', 'J', 'S', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'N', 'N', 'A'}; then you will get a different output, you are only able to change the first occurrence of, say character 'A'.

Comment: @Juniar - In OP's original code, as soon as `arrayA[i] == arrayB[j]`, `arrayA[i]` will be set to `' '`, so it isn't going to match any further elements of `arrayB` (unless they are also `' '`).

Comment: I guess that makes sense, No duplicates. Then you won`t have to iterate through the entire array. This has the best case scenario of O(1).

Comment: @Juniar - Well, not O(1) because the outer loop still has to iterate over the entire length of `arrayA`, so best case would be O(`arrayA.length`). That would only be achieved if `arrayA[0] == arrayB[0]` and the rest of `arrayA` (beyond index 0) was initially equal to `' '`.